# Why is this delegate method automatically called in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, delegates

I'm going through this book called "cocoa programming for mac os x" and I just started with delegates. This whole thing with delegates is still a little bit wacky to me but I think I just need to let it settle.

However there was this one exercise where I should implement a delegate of the main window so that if resized height is always 2xwidth.

So I got 4 files:

- AppDelegate.h
- AppDelegate.m
- WindowDelegate.h
- WindowDelegate.m

AppDelegate are just the two standard files that get created when you open a new Cocoa project. I had to look up the solution because I didn't quite know how to accomplish this task.
The solution was just to create a new cocoa class, "WindowDelegat.h/.m" and add this to it's implementation file:

```
- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize {
NSSize newSize = frameSize;
newSize.height = newSize.width * 2;
return newSize;
}
```

Then I opened the interface builder, added a new object and made it my WindowDelegate. I then had to ctrl drag from the WindowDelegate to the actual window and made it the window's delegate.
Clicked run and it worked. Yay! But why?
First I thought that "windowWillResize" is just one of these callback functions that get's called as soon as the window is resized but it isn't. Normally methods get invoked because the general lifecycle of an program invokes them or because they are an @IBAction, a button or different control elements. 
But "windowWillResize" is non of them. So why is it called?

EDIT: Problem solved! Thanks a lot!

Now I'm trying to connect the delegate to the window programmatically. Therefore I deleted the referencing outlet from WindowDelegate to the actual window in interface builder. It works but I just want to verify that this it the correct way how it's done:

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "WindowDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) WindowDelegate *winDeleg;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [_window setOpaque:NO];
    NSColor *transparentColor = [NSColor colorWithDeviceRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    [_window setBackgroundColor:transparentColor];
    NSSize initialSize = NSMakeSize(100, 200);
    [_window setContentSize:initialSize];

    _winDeleg = [[WindowDelegate alloc] init];
    [_window setDelegate: _winDeleg];
}
@end
```

WindowDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface WindowDelegate : NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>

@end
```

WindowDelegate.m

```
#import "WindowDelegate.h"

@implementation WindowDelegate

- (NSSize)windowWillResize:(NSWindow *)sender toSize:(NSSize)frameSize {
    NSSize newSize = frameSize;
    newSize.height = newSize.width * 2;
    return newSize;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}
@end
```

Why does the @property of WindowDelegate need to be strong?
And isn't my winDeleg an object? Why do I have to access it through _winDeleg when it's an object. I though the underscore is used to access variables?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Clicked run and it worked. Yay! But why?

Because instances of [NSWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class) have a [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSWindow/delegate) property that can point to any object that implements the [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intf/c:objc(pl)NSWindowDelegate) protocol, and that protocol includes the [`-windowWillResize:toSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSWindowDelegate/windowWillResize:toSize:) method.

Read that a few times. The reason it's important is that you can create your own object, say that it implements `NSWindowDelegate`, implement `-windowWillResize:toSize:`, and set that object as your window's delegate. Then, whenever the user resizes the window, your method will be called and can modify the proposed new size.

> Normally methods get invoked because the general lifecycle of an program invokes them or because they are an @IBAction, a button or different control elements. But "windowWillResize" is non of them. So why is it called?

This really isn't so different. Think of delegates as "helper objects." They let you customize the behavior of an object without having to create a whole new subclass. The `NSWindowDelegate` object is essentially a contract that the `NSWindow` promises to follow: whenever certain things happen, such as the user resizing the window, the window will call certain methods in its delegate object, if the delegate exists and implements those methods. In the case of `NSApplication`, a lot of those delegate methods are application lifecycle events, like the app starting up or quitting or getting a message from the operating system. In the case of `NSWindow`, delegate methods correspond to interesting events that can happen to a window, like the user moving it, hiding it, showing it, maximizing it, moving it to a different screen, etc. Other classes, like text views or network connections or movie players, have their own sets of interesting events and their own delegate protocols to match.

Note that methods marked `IBAction` really aren't delegate methods, they're just methods that get called by objects like controls that use a target/action paradigm. The `IBAction` keyword lets the IDE know which methods it should present as possible actions for things like buttons. You often find actions in window controllers and view controllers, and those objects frequently act as a delegate for some other object, but the actions themselves aren't part of the delegate protocol. For example, `NSTableView` takes a delegate object that determines how the table will act and what's displayed in it. It often makes sense for the view controller that manages the table to be the table's delegate, and that same view controller might also manage some buttons and contain the action methods that said buttons trigger, but the actions aren't part of the `NSTableViewDelegate` protocol and you therefore wouldn't call them `delegate methods.`

Comment: Ok! And by ctrl dragging from the object to the window in interface builder I'm automatically setting the delegate property to the WindowDelegate I created.
And by doing this, ":NSObject <NSWindowDelegate>"protocol is also added to my WindowDelegate class? Because I can't see it but it just works.

Comment: Exactly. You defined a class (`WindowDelegate`) and then created an instance of that class and made it the window's delegate.

Comment: A protocol just defines an interface, a list of methods that the object either must or might implement. (Methods in a protocol can be optional or required.) You can check whether an object conforms to a protocol (every object has a `-conformsToProtocol:` method) and whether it implements a given method (`-respondsToSelector:`). You usually don't care what type a delegate object is, you only care about what methods it implements.